# ASP.NET MVC 3 how to implement many to many relationship in Create View

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have quite a complex class that has three one-to-many relationships and two many-to-many relationships with other classes. What I would like to do is to enable the user to fill all the details one by one - in one step or even better in multiple steps (wizard).

My class is called PeriodicTask - user has to select one Server object (which represents SQL Server instance ) and depending on the selection I need to present the user with the ability to select which databases he wants to use ( the best option would be to use checkboxes). I don't really know how to achieve this.

I would start with creating an action that returns JSON with databases for the selected server. It'll be invoked by jQuery. So far so good, but what to do then?

Should I add `<input type="checkbox">` to the form for every database or maybe create another form and post to some other action? How to parse that when the form is submitted? Can I split it somehow into smaller steps ? HTTP is stateless so I somehow need to pass or remember the data that was previously submitted - how?

PS> I'm using Entity Framework here, so part of the class hierarchy is as follows:

[image: Class diagram]

Comment: It seems that you have managed to combine the Entity Diagram designer in Visual Studio, with ASP.NET MVC 3. I have no idea how to do that — [would you post to my question about this and explain how you did it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263795) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

1. User selects server instance from
   dropdownlist.
2. After selection dropdownlist fires "change "event, handler of
   which loads databases list to form using ajax (your action can provide JSON or html with checkboxes)
3. User selects checkboxes and presses
   submit button
4. On submit you collect
       checked item and post to action
       using javascript

Comment: This is quite obvious, the problem is how to do it without much effort. I could of course use FormCollection and do it all manually. Another option that I've learned about a few minutes ago is creating custom model binder. The question really is if this is necessary or maybe there is a simpler out-of-the-box solution..

Comment: You don't have to create custom ModelBinder. ASP.NET MVC offers this functionality out of the box. I answered how to do it in [this] post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997695/how-to-pass-a-list-of-selected-objects-from-javascript-in-an-action-in-mvc/5997769#5997769)

Comment: Thanks for answer :) If I understood correctly you're suggesting that I should use mvc3 json model binder. All is fine and well, but that would probably require splitting the whole process into two separate actions - one for PeriodicTask and one for adding Databases to it - this would break the transaction and make server side validation impossible(I need at least 1 db selected), unless using JSON means that I don't have to split that into separate actions ?

Comment: To be precisely, I'm suggesting to use JsonValueProviderFactory. But it enabled by default in asp.net mvc 3, so you don't have to care about it, but make sure you have specified correct content type (Json). Regarding transaction boundaries - you can do it in single transaction if you will post all data in one request. But can make as many Ajax requests as you want to show any necessary data to user

Comment: I would like to do it in one request. I'm just curious if it really can get populated as one PeriodicTask object with Databases collection set appropriately. I guess I'll have to try..

Answer (score 0):

I would look at creating helpers for each of the options that would be self contained, they could maintain the state themselves.

Another cool option would be to create a tree view, where the root level is your server and next level is database. Load the data into a ViewModel so that it can be used as the data source for a tree view.  It seems like a nice interface for what you have.

Believe it or not the Microsoft site is a great place to start when learning MVC

http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Thanks for answer. Tree would be great if PeriodicTask was in many-to-many relationship with Server, but I would like to keep one-to-many and I have good reasons to do so (but that's a longer story). Eventually I've decided not to include those many-to-many relationships while creating periodic task and after commiting to the db user is redirected to the edit action which has links to "manage databases" and "manage destinations" actions. This makes periodic tasks not fully validates, because to make it work I need at leas one db and one destination, but I guess I can live with that.