# Is it possible to use the VS Entity Diagram designer with ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-model

The introductory videos for ASP.NET MVC 3 imply that the desired workflow is for me to declare classes that define my model (code-first design).

This strikes me as weird, since Visual Studio has a nice Entity Diagram designer which can generate such classes with navigation properties, etc.

Is it possible to use that Entity Diagram designer to design the model (model-first design), and have ASP.NET MVC 3 understand the generated classes as its model?

Please provide precise steps if possible :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible.

(Anyone wishing to prove me wrong and show how it can be done, please be my guest, but please provide steps :) )

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is called Model First design.  Most of the video's you see have used the Code First approach.  There are benefits to both.

This video should help you out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff628199

UPDATE:

Here are the steps I use:

1. Create new MVC Project, I use the default internet project.
2. Right click on Models folder, Create new Entity Model (choose empty model)
3. Drag an Entity onto the designer, name it User.
4. Right click on designer and choose Generate Database
5. Use context and entity in project.

It's not difficult, and it works just fine.  And it works the same way Model First works anywhere else.

Comment: Where’s the connection with MVC? I know how to create an entity model, that’s not the issue. The issue is getting it to work with MVC...

Comment: @Timwi - There is no connection with MVC.  MVC doesn't care what data model you use.  You just use it like you do anywhere else.

Comment: You should test this before you make claims like that. If that were the case, I obviously wouldn’t be asking this question. By default, the Entity Designer creates objects that derive from `EntityObject`, and MVC doesn’t like that (it explicitly says that in the exception message).

Comment: @Timwi - That's not true.  I know exactly what i'm talking about.  MVC has *NOTHING* to do with the database technology. It doesn't define it, use it in any way.  The error you are seeing is related to something else, and you will have to give more info on it to get help with that.

Comment: You should *still* test this before you make claims. Here’s some steps for you to try. Start a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project (Internet). In the Models folder, Add → ADO.NET Entity Data Model (Empty model), then define a “User” entity. Then try to create a Controller for it. You get this: http://screencast.com/t/bJLiSbSon — Notice the last 5 words. (If you define POCO classes first, then create the controller, and then replace the POCOs with Entity-Diagram-generated classes, you get the same message as a run-time exception.)

Comment: @Timwi - I have used Model First many times in MVC.  The problem you are having is something other than a general incompatibility between MVC and EF.  I don't understand your comment about "adding a controller for it".  You don't add controllers for entities.  Can you provide exact steps that cause the problem?

Comment: I don’t see how you can possibly have used MVC (which stands for “model, view, **controller”**) without creating controllers. Sorry. −1. (Also, this question is not generally about EF (Entity Framework) but the entity designer specifically.)

Comment: Furthermore, I don’t see why I should be providing the *wrong* steps (which I already have). I asked this question in order to receive *answers* that provide *me* with the *correct* steps.

Comment: @Timwi - I didn't say I don't create controllers.  I said, you don't create controllers *FOR ENTITIES*.  You ceate controllers based on logical areas, not based on your entity structure.

Comment: @Timwi - I'm asking you to provide the steps you used because you are clearly going wrong somewhere.  The "right steps" depends greatly on what you're doing, and I can't psychicly determine the context upon which the error is occuring.  Have you noticed nobody else has commented?  That's because your question does not contain enough information, and those that are experienced are just ignoring it. (and frankly, given your antagonistic response, i'm beginning to wish I had as well)

Comment: @Timwi - You do know you have to generate the database before you try to use it, right?  Did you miss that step?

Comment: Is all this hostility really necessary, @Timwi? Perhaps Mystere Man did test whatever he replied with, and the misunderstanding is elsewhere? (which, from further comments, seems likely)